# Using aurelia-ux with EcmaScript

Tags: aurelia

Can we use Aurelia ux (https://github.com/aurelia/ux) with EcmaScript instead of TypeScript ? Did somebody try ?

What was said here http://blog.aurelia.io/2016/11/04/introducing-aurelia-ux/ is not clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Anything developed by the Aurelia team is going to be just as usable in ECMAScript as it is in TypeScript.

Aurelia UX is itself being developed in TypeScript, but that does not in any way preclude you from using ECMAScript.

Also, the blog post you linked to states:

> ECMAScript developers do not fear! Our team is split 50/50 between ES and TS, so you can bet that UX is going to work great regardless of what your preferred language is. We're committed to that.

I'm not sure how much more unequivocal the post could have been.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I didn't understand well blog post. I thought that it is planned to work with ES projects in the future, but now I see that my thoughts doesn't have any sense.